# Why System.getProperty("user.name"); does not work from command line?

Tags: java, path, filesystems

The following line of code works fine with Eclipse

```
Path file = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"),"Desktop","Peppe.txt");
```

however when I try to run it from a terminal it gives me back this error message

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /root/Desktop/Peppe.txt
```

In theory `System.getProperty("user.name")` should return a platform indipendent bit of root path? isn't it?

Comment: The problem is that with Eclipse it works fine but it doesn't from a terminal using the same computer. Java 7 on a Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run the app as a different user between Eclipse and the command line.

Comment: you run your programm with root login or user login?

Comment: What happens when you do: `java -Duser.home=$HOME <program>`?

Answer (score 1):

You are running the code as `root` and it's quite likely that root doesn't have a Desktop.

I wouldn't assume the code is not behaving correctly, instead I would assume you need to understand what it means.

Comment: How can I do then? If I do not run it as root it says "Access denied" as I am trying to access a file (even though I changed the PosixPermissions hence added OTHERS_WRITE

Comment: Actually the "Access Denied" error message appears only with a particular file which has the same PosixFilePermissions of other which are actually working without any error message. :O strange

Comment: Perhaps the directory doesn't have permission or the directory is a file or the file is a directory. root can prevent itself from accessing something (even if it could change it if it wanted to)  Even `root` cannot confuse files and directories (too much)